# How can I set a lower case environment variable in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a docker container in which I am running a software that expects one of its configuration parameters as an environment variable with lower case characters in its name. I want to set this environment variable from my docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
    BaSyxRegistry_registry.backend: SQL
```

However when i run the compose command the variables name is ALL CAPS:
[BASYXREGISTRY_REGISTRY.BACKEND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQSWW.png)

Even though I specified the variable name as BaSyxRegistry_registry.backend it is instead called BASYXREGISTRY_REGISTRY.BACKEND so the software can not read it and my configuration does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in quotes, like this

```
environment:
    'BaSyxRegistry_registry.backend': SQL
```

The way I tested it was with this docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: debian
    environment:
      'BaSyxRegistry_registry.backend': SQL
    command: env
```

When run, it prints out

```
app_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
app_1  | HOSTNAME=4ada81304d04
app_1  | BaSyxRegistry_registry.backend=SQL
app_1  | HOME=/root
```

I just tried without the quotes and it's still in lower case. So you are correct that the quotes don't matter.

What is your host OS and what versions of docker and docker-compose are you using? My setup is

- Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5
- Docker: 20.10.22
- Docker-compose: 1.29.2

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, neither ' nor " change anything about the behaviour.

Comment: @MatthiasGellrich You are correct that the quotes don't change anything. But I have lower case both with and without. I've expanded my answer. Can you run the same test and maybe add info about your setup?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the docker-compose you provided. My problem was actually two problems combined:
1. Docker desktop showing the variable names in ALL_CAPS, even though they are set correctly
2. the image I was using not handling env variables with periods in their name correctly, which is why I was not able to check the variable via the command line.

So it seems like everything is actually working correctly (except the variable list in docker desktop UI)

Thanks a lot for your help.